# Comparing array value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was working on my project where I had to compare some ID's and check if they are the same or not. First time I saw something like this

```
if (found[myRes[i].eventId] === 1) {
```

So I have array myRes that looks like this:

```
myRes.push({'eventId':42,'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Mike, Allan"});

myRes.push({'eventId':42,'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Gates, Bill"});

myRes.push({'eventId':19,'eventName':"Spring 2016",'rCustomer':"John, Bill"});

myRes.push({'eventId':19,'eventName':"Spring 2016",'rCustomer':"Adams, Ron"});

myRes.push({'eventId':31,'eventName':"May Test 1",'rCustomer':"Steve, Marie"});

myRes.push({'eventId':42,'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Ariel, Bill"});

myRes.push({'eventId':32,'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Ron, Nill"});

myRes.push({'eventId':32,'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Kim, Alen"});

myRes.push({'eventId':32,'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Will, Huges"});

myRes.push({'eventId':32,'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Seth, Peak"});
```

I have solution for my problem but I do not understand completely how it works. Here is the code that I use:

```
var found = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myRes.length; i++) {
    if (found[myRes[i].eventId] === 1) {
        $('#row_' + myRes[i].eventId).append('<tr><td>'+myRes[i].some element+'</td></tr></tbody></table>');
    } else {
        found[myRes[i].eventId] = 1;
        $('.myReservation').append('<table><tr></tr><thead><tr><th >'+myRes[i].eventName+'</th></tr></thead><tbody id="row_' + myRes[i].eventId + '"><tr><td>'+myRes[i].someelement+'</td></tr>');
    }
}
```

Here is the method that I used and did not work, this method outputted same event Name twice.

```
var eventId;

  for(var i=0; i< myRes.length; i++){
    if(eventId === myRes[i].eventId){
      $('#row_' + myRes[i].eventId).append('<td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td>');
    }else{
      eventId = myRes[i].eventId;
      $('.myReservation').append('<tr id="row_'+myRes[i].eventId+'"><td><b>Event: '+myRes[i].eventName+'</b></td><td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td></tr>');
    }
  }
```

Output from code above:

```
Event: Test 1   Mike, Allan Gates, Bill
Event: Spring 2016  John, Bill  Adams, Ron
Event: May Test 1   Steve, Marie
Event: Test 1   Ariel, Bill
Event: Fall 2016    Ron, Nill   Kim, Alen   Will, Huges Seth, Peak
```

1. My question is what actually happens in my if statement?
2. Does if statement basically looks for specific id that is assigned
   in found array and if does not exist in found array then left side
   of my if statement is 1 that will execute if statement? Or something
   else is behind that.
3. Also in else statement new value is assigned to found array and set
   to 1. How that actually looks in found array then? Is that specific
   ID set to 1?
4. If anyone can explain this to me I would appreciate. I tried to
   output found array to the screen but still that did not gave me
   enough to understand how this works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your eventId keys are storing string values. When you are using the '===' you are saying this must be an exact match. "1" does not equal 1 in this case. http://jsbin.com/xevisohozi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You have a typo in the second code block or have not provided a complete, working piece of code: you don't seem to have a `myId` property, so that means you assign `undefined` to the `evenId` variable in the `else` block and from that moment on the `if` condition is always `true` for the rest of the iterations.

Comment: @MikeCheel He's not comparing with the `eventID` keys, he's using `eventID` as the key in `found`, and he does store integers in `found`.

Comment: What is `confId`? Another typo?

Comment: @Barmar This post has been edited. I was explaining the if 'if(eventId === myRes[i].eventId)' and his original data sample had the values as strings not numerics as they are now. And there was a confId value as well earlier I believe.

Comment: You still have `eventId = myRes[i].myId;` in your `else` clause. How many typos are we going to have to wade through? Please paste the actual code, because otherwise there's no way to know if the problem you're having is related to code that you didn't copy correctly.

Comment: Everything should match now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only compares with the most recent `eventId`, since there's just a single variable. This would work OK if you had `myRes` sorted by `eventId`, since it would group all the reservations for same event together and just show the event name once at the beginning of the group. But since the events are scattered in the array, it shows the event name whenever it changes, so you get it multiple times.

The way the first code works is that it uses the event ID as the index in the `found` array. Initially the array is empty, so `found[anything]` will be undefined. The first time it encounters an event ID in the loop, `found[myRes[i].eventId]` will be undefined, which is treated as `false` by `if`. That makes it go to the `else` block, which displays the event name and sets `found[myRes[i].eventId] = 1`. The next time it encounters that same event ID in the loop, the test succeeds, so it performs the code in the `if` block, which just displays the customer data.

For example, `myRes[0].eventId` is `42`. So the first iteration of the loop does

```
if (found[42] === 1)
```

Since this fails, it does:

```
found[42] = 1;
```

in the `else` block. In later iterations of the loop, when `myRes[i].eventId` is again `42` (such as the 2nd and 6th reservations), the test

```
if (found[42] === 1)
```

will succeed.

Comment: @Bamar that answered my question. I better understand now how each code works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to learn basic syntax. When you see an expression like `found[myRes[i].eventId] = 1`, break it down into its parts. First understand what `myRes[i].eventId` is, then it's just using that as the index in the `found` array.

Comment: I knew what I have stored in myRes[i].eventId but I did not understand how that works if I put inside of array and how that is equal to 1.

Comment: The line `found[XXX] = 1` sets it equal to 1, that shouldn't be confusing.

Comment: Does that store value 1 for index 42 for example?

Comment: Yes, `found[42] = 1` stores the value 1 in index 42. This is very basic array stuff.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. For me that was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first code block works and the second not, is that the second only detects duplicate `eventId` values when they are consecutive. The second method only retains the last different value of `eventId`, while the first method retains all of them in the `found` object, and that is what is needed to make it work.

The second method could work if you would first sort the `myRes` array on `eventId`.

#### About method 1

Here is how it works. This line:

```
found[myRes[i].eventId] = 1;
```

sets an array element in the `found` array to 1. If the array is not yet long enough it is made long enough. It may then look like this when `eventId` is 42 (there are 42 empty elements preceding the 1):

```
[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1]
```

As other values of `eventId` are found, the same happens again, and after a few of such assignments you get something like this for the `found` array:

```
[,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,1,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,1]
```

Now, the `if` statement will check if there is a 1 at the index corresponding to `eventId`. If this is the case, it was found before.

Note that the value 1 has no particular significance. You could do the same with `true` or 2 for that matter. As long as your test is on the same value as the one assigned in the `else` block.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! One more question, what actually happens in if (found[myRes[i].eventId] === 1) and what in this part found[myRes[i].eventId] = 1; ?

Comment: His confusion is at a much more basic level, he doesn't understand what `found[myRes[0].eventId] = 1` does.

Comment: Added an explanation about that. Hope it clarifies it.